# What is the difference betwen TINYINT(1) and Boolean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, what is the difference betwen TINYINT(1) and Boolean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1).

There is no difference.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: if only every SO member read the documentation - amount of questions would decrease to at least an order of magnitude

Comment: Right, it's easy to say "read the manual" AFTER you already know the answer and where it is in said manual.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: "mysql boolean" google request 1st result is the referred page

Answer (score 2):

There is no. `BOOLEAN` is an alias to `TINYINT(1)`

Answer (score 0):

BOOL or BOOLEAN and just synonyms for TINYINT(1)